# HSDPA modem, how to mount SD card on Linux?

Tags: mount, udev

```
scsi19 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
scsi 19:0:0:0: CD-ROM            ZCOption HSUPA Modem           PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
scsi 19:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
scsi 19:0:0:1: Direct-Access     SD       HSUPA Modem           PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
sd 19:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
sd 19:0:0:1: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

How can I reach the SD card on sg2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will mount the sdcard to /tmp/sdcard. You may need to pass in -t option to mount with the name of the filesystem on the card. use "man mount" to learn more.

```
mkdir /tmp/sdcard
mount /dev/sdc /tmp/sdcard
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was putting the SD card in the wrong slot :/. Sorry for the amateurish way of asking a question, I did not copy in the error message complaining about how sg2 was not a block device.